# Is it good to pass java map to view instead of form?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

What about best practices? Is it good? Or better is pass models to view with any form wrapper? What do you think?

Comment: I have trouble to grasp the meaning of 'pass models to view with any form wrapper'.

Comment: You can pass any object to the render() method.
It can be just Model or Form<Model> (or DynamicForm) instance

Comment: Right. I use both, pure models and models wrapped in a Form. Wrapped in a Form it has the advantage that the validation errors are accessible, e.g. the global errors with `form.globalErrors`. On the other side with a pure model the model's fields are a little easier to access: `myModel.myField` versus `form(myField).value` - it looks a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on the use case you have. Both passing a model instance and a model instance wrapped in a form have their advantages.

As Kris pointed out, having a form gives you access to validation errors and so on.
Accessing fields directly from the model is of course, on the other hand, much simpler with a model instance.

Please *don't* just pass some maps with data (something like `Map[String, Object]`) - if you can work with objects, do it, that's the idea of OO.

**In summary:** if your template deals with form manipulation (editing, submission, ...) - use a model wrapped in a form. If you just want to display some data or similar - grab your model instance and provide it to the view, without any additional overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is use an standanlone HTML 5 app to return the HTML pages and use play for the others server side processing (Accesing DB, control business logic, etc.)

You gain better separation between the front-end and the back-end.